# Are there any ATxmega chips with bi-directional SPi ports?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, solar-cell, microprocessor, atmel

I searched the datasheets shown for the ATxmega chips in the Microcontroller Selector, shown on the left side of http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/default.aspx, for any ATxmega chips with bi-directional SPi ports, but I was unable to find any.

I know ATmega chips have bi-directional SPi ports, but I want to take advantage of the features in the ATxmega chips for my solar car project.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by bi-directional, and what makes you think that it is missing from these?  Able to operate as both master and slave?  Able to use a single data line instead of distinct MISO & MOSI?  Note that in the later case, even if it wasn't supported you could accomplish it by using two spi engines, one as a master and one as a slave, connected in parallel (and it looks like the USARTs can function as SPI masters).  And of course you can also skip the SPI engine and just bitbang any pins you like.

Comment: Here is a [snippet](http://oi40.tinypic.com/2ewf9di.jpg) of the [ATtiny48/88 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/8008S.pdf). That is exactly what I'm talking about. An "8-bit bi-directional I/O port with internal pull-up".

See the datasheet's notes on the ports for the other questions posed.

I'm aware of the latter points you brought up, but, the requirements my professor told me are final. FYI, this is for my fall semester Senior EE lab.

Comment: Well, you are confused about what you asking for, as SPI engines are not "8 bit bi-directional I/O port"s - though they may (on the ATMEGA, and presumably on the XMEGA as well) share pins with such, the pin being used for one function or the other depending on the settings of a configuration register.

Comment: The only valid answer to this question is "All of them", as I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I'm confused about many things because I know very few things. Thank you for the further explanation Chris.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: Yes, it is, more or less, but helloworld explained it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume this is what you are looking for:

1. An Atmel xmega micro-controller
2. Has IO pins configurable as input (with optional pull-up resistors), or as output
3. Has both slave and master SPI functionality (preferably hardware support)

Comment below if this isn't exactly what you're looking for.

Pretty much all xmega (maybe even all) devices feature IO pins with select-able internal pullup/pulldown resistors.

This is the IO block diagram for an [xmega-AU device](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8331-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-XMEGA-AU_Manual.pdf):

[image]

Notice that the top-right section of the general IO pin block diagram has select-able internal pull-up and pull-down functionality, as well as a pull keep or totem pole input options. This is common across all IO pins configurable as general IO pins.

That just leaves hardware SPI functionality. Luckily, the same xmega-AU device supports hardware SPI in both master and slave modes. See chapter 22 for full details on what is supported.

This is not exclusive to the xmega-AU series, this just happened to be the first one I clicked on. IIRC, pretty much all xmega chips have the same or very similar general IO block diagram, and they also support hardware SPI in master and slave modes.

Comment: Thank you helloworld. I assumed that the xmega chips would state exactly what I was looking for in the datasheets, as I quoted above. But, obviously they are built in and not explicitly noted. My stupid mistake.